# InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with: status = StatusCode.FAILED_PRECONDITION, details = "Attempting to use uninitialized value dense_2/bias

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

Getting following error from my python grpc client when trying predicting wuth the tf-serving server:

```
_InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.FAILED_PRECONDITION
    details = "Attempting to use uninitialized value dense_2/bias
     [[{{node dense_2/bias/read}}]]"
    debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1654790154.977771219","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:10.1.25.14:9002","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":903,"grpc_message":"Attempting to use uninitialized value dense_2/bias\n\t [[{{node dense_2/bias/read}}]]","grpc_status":9}"
>
```

I found description of problem but it is not informative for me

> Operation was rejected because the system is not in a state required for the operation’s execution. (https://grpc.github.io/grpc/python/grpc.html#grpc-status-code)

I am using:

```
python 3.9 
tensorflow-serving-api==2.8.0
tensorflow==2.8.0
```

What can be the reason for this error and how it could be fix?